# How to handle categorical features in K-means?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, python-3.x

I am working on clustering algorithms. I am working with titanic dataset. It contains 6 categorical features. I used k-means algorithm on this dataset. I am using label encoding for categorical features. But I found that categorical features should use euclidean distance. It should use [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). So, how to make k-means work finely on mixed features? I don't need other algorithm. I just want to work with k-means only on mixed features dataset.

Comment: You should use one-hot enconding rather than label encoding

Comment: How one-hot encoding solves the problem? since using one-hot encoding also results 0s and 1s.when i apply k-means it calculates distance.so it may results in decimal .How to solve that. @Chopin

Answer (score 2):

Label encoding is not a good idea if the nature of categories are not ordinal (it is actually not my favorite anyways). Use one-hot encoding and see how it works. You may apply a feature extraction on top of it, e.g. PCA, to reduce the noise coming from sparsity. The other idea is to label categories by their fraction in the feature, for example:

```
[a,b,b,c,a,a] --> [3/6, 2/6, 2/6, 1/6, 3/6, 3/6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to encode the data will be through any encoding mechanism like label encoder etc. But before handling the categorical variable check the correlation of a categorical variable with the target variable using the feature selection methods like chi square test with selectKbest.

Answer (score 0):

You can quantify correlation, or more precisely `association`, between categorical variables using something like cross-entropy. There’s an available library `dython` to compute such association values. Also I am curious why do you want to do clustering ? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think the k-prototype algorithm is what you are looking for.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1009769707641